# How to print selected/multiple Contact Profile "Print Summary"?

Tags: wordpress

I have around 1000 contacts and I want to print selected profile summary.
I found a "Print Summary" in Actions of the Contact profile page, but can only seem to print one summary at a time. 
Is there a way to print multiple profile summaries at one time in the format the "Print Summary" prints or is a custom report going to be needed to print these summaries? And how to do it?

Thanks in advanced.

CiviCRM Version: 4.7.19
Wordpress Version: 4.7.5

Comment: I would also like to be able to select multiple contacts and print summaries for them. A report isn't going to do for me, because I need to be able to print image files as part of the summary. I suspect there is no out of the box way to do this, but I suspect it wouldn't be hard to develop an extension to add this - which would be a good candidate for core, imo. I'd see if my organization could contribute to such development.

Comment: Phil - what CMS are you on. Drupal users would probably get a better solution using Views

Comment: petednz - just finding your comment. We use Joomla.

Comment: @PhilMoriceBrubaker - it might be that adding image support to civireport would be a flexible way to help you with this. You could submit it to extendedreports extension rather than core if it is a bit more experimental

Answer (score 1):

This might be quicker/fewer clicks than totally manual printing when you are dealing with dozens or hundreds of contacts. Still not a great option, though.

1. Get a list of all the ContactIDs that you want to print.
2. Merge each CID into the appropriate "Print Summary" URL for your CMS. For Joomla, it is [domain]/administrator/?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/contact/view/print&reset=1&print=1&cid=xxxx
3. Put the list of merged URLs into your favorite text editor that creates automatic links, and click on each one.

Not really an answer to how to print multiple at once, but it might be a useful workflow for a non-programmer until a proper solution is devised.